# How do I make this script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

I want a script that uses these options in CMD:

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

Then ask for a Vendor ie. HP or Dell.
Then the output should be something like `vendor-serialnumber` from wmic, then add a - in the serialnumber, like this:

```
YHT3-1234
```

the "-" should always be before the last 4 digits in the serialnumber,
so the final output would be something like :

```
HP-YHT3-1234
```

Comment: Have you used the following command when testing WMIC, `BIOS Get Manufacturer`? Surely `Hewlett-Packard` or similar is returned, so why ask the end user to type in the vendor? Don't open the door to potential problems with your scripts, and the number one problem is always going to be the end user!

Comment: I dont want the full output length. i want just a short indentifier. so if the script ask something like "What is the vendor: %input%" then %output%-Serialnumber with the - infront of the last 4 digits/letters it would be great. FInal output should be something like: %input%-YTHE-1234

Comment: If the `Manufacturer` string contains `HP` or `Hewlett-Packard`, then your script can detect that and prefix `HP` automatically instead of asking the end user to determine it, and type it correctly. The same is true for the string `Dell`. Like I said, if the information is already available to the script, and using the same WMI query, then there's no reason to involve the end user, thus allowing for potential problems.

Comment: Does `wmic BIOS get Version` return something useful with respect to the vendor? on my system, it returns something like `<short_vendor_name> - <version_number>`. If this does not help, why not using a translation list: `for %%K in ("Dell Inc.=Dell" "Microsoft Corp.=MS" "Hewlett-Packard=HP") do for /F "tokens=1* delims== eol==" %%I in ("%%~K") do if /I "%Manufacturer%"=="%%I" set "Vendor=%%J"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example to show you how to introduce the hyphen/dash into your serial number, together with some additional work to auto detect the Manufacturer, and shorten to an identifier as necessary.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "Vendor="
Set "Serial="
For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe BIOS Where "Manufacturer Like '%%Hewlett-Packard%%' Or Manufacturer Like '%%Dell%%' And SerialNumber Is Not NULL" Get Manufacturer^,SerialNumber /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do If Not Defined Vendor (Set "Vendor=%%G") Else Set "Serial=%%G"
If Not Defined Vendor GoTo :EOF
If "%Vendor:Dell=%" == "%Vendor%" (Set "Serial=HP-%Serial:~,-4%-%Serial:~-4%") Else Set "Serial=Dell-%Serial:~,-4%-%Serial:~-4%"
Echo %Serial%
Pause
```

Obviously if there are a lot of Manufacturers then additional work would need to be done.

---

As an unnecessary courtesy, here is the same methodology, just this time affording end user the opportunity to break the code, or corrupt the result:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "Serial="
For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe BIOS Where "SerialNumber Is Not NULL" Get SerialNumber /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do Set "Serial=%%G"
If Not Defined Serial GoTo :EOF
Set /P "Vendor=Type the name of the Computer Manufacturer, and press ENTER>"
Echo %Vendor%-%Serial:~,-4%-%Serial:~-4%
Pause
```

---

Based upon a very limited test of one HP notebook and the comments by KJ below, the following idea may also be useful:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "Serial="
Set "Vendor="
For /F Tokens^=2^,4^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 CSProduct Assoc:List 2^>NUL') Do Set "Serial=%%G" & For /F %%I In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile
 "-Join '%%H'.ToUpper()[0..3]"') Do Set "Vendor=%%I" 
If Not Defined Serial GoTo :EOF
Echo %Vendor%-%Serial:~,-4%-%Serial:~-4%
Pause
```

This uses PowerShell just to return up to the first four characters in upper case from the string returned as the `Name` value from the `CSProduct` alias of WMIC. So `Compaq` would return `COMP`, `Dell` as `DELL`, `Lenovo` as `LENO` `Samsung` as `SAMS` etc. This would then be prefixed to the serial number, *(split as before)*, which in my test was returned as the ComputerSystemProduct IdentifyingNumber.

Comment: This outputs the full length of the manufacturer. I just want it to add an input you type yourself into the final output. So it would be %input%Serialnu-mber. But thanks for the amazing script =)

Comment: No it does not, the string value assigned to `%Vendor%`, contains the full Manuafacturer string, however, the `%Serial%`, using the code above will only begin with `HP-` or `Dell-` and it will be followed by the returned serial number with the last four characters separated by a hyphen/dash, as requested. The only possible output for the `%Vendor%` string values using the code as submitted above, can be those containing, the exact sequence of characters `Hewlett-Packard`, or those containing the exact sequence of characters `Dell` anywhere within them. The `If` command then shortens it.

Comment: BTW @SemtexSoup, I've provided the non robust and crazy code at the bottom of my answer too, so you can continue to introduce unnecessary problems should you wish. Please be aware, as I've already mentioned, the end user could just hit `[ENTER]`, or could type anything at all they wanted at the `Set /P` prompt. This includes not just a full Manufacturer string, _(which you do not want)_, or general typing errors; but also poison characters, or malicious strings, _(which may exit the script, damage your computer or its data, or just be impossible to `echo` without enabling delayed expansion)_.

Comment: Well as a coincidence the PC I'm currently repairing, is a HP, and inside it `Insyde` is menioed in the `Caption`, the `Description`, the `Name`, the `SoftwareElementID`, and the `BIOSVersion`. The latter is a string array containing, some of those previously mentioned togeter with the `Version` which is inclidentally the string `HPQOEM - 1`. however the `Manufacturer` string is still `Hewlett-Packard`. As is usual, many of the values are dependent upon the Manufacturer configuring things properly. @KJ, what does `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe SystemEnclosure Get Manufacturer` return?

Comment: Alternatively I'm sure that either `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe BaseBoard Get Manufacturer`, or probably better `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe CSProduct Get Vendor` should get the information we need. At present however, regardless of that, I've posted a version which allows a perfectly working end user to input the required string.

Comment: Thanks @KJ, I've added another hopeful idea to the foot of my answer based upon the very poor testing we've done, just in case it provides something useful. If nothing else, it shows a method of returning up to the first four characters of a string in upper case, via PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get it with PowerShell. Unless your organization has banned it, PowerShell is available on all supported Windows systems.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$x=Get-CimInstance CIM_BIOSElement;"
    "'{0}-{1}-{2}' -f"
    "@($x.Manufacturer, $x.SerialNumber.Substring(0,$x.SerialNumber.Length - 4),"
    "$x.SerialNumber.Substring($x.SerialNumber.Length - 4))"') DO (SET "RESULT=%A")
ECHO RESULT is %RESULT%
```

Remember to double the PERCENT SIGN characters if this goes into a .bat/.cmd script.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$x=Get-CimInstance CIM_BIOSElement;"
    "'{0}-{1}-{2}' -f"
    "@($x.Manufacturer, $x.SerialNumber.Substring(0,$x.SerialNumber.Length - 4),"
    "$x.SerialNumber.Substring($x.SerialNumber.Length - 4))"') DO (SET "RESULT=%%A")
ECHO RESULT is %RESULT%
```